# how to make android beep in only one ear?

Tags: java, android, beep

I am still new to android and currently I am working on a project, where I have to guide a person using audio signals.
What I actually want to do is beep at a frequency only in one ear to tell the person to either turn left or turn right. When directing straight both ears will be beeping.

I found a number of examples here on how to generate the beep sound on android.

Here is an example of how to generate an arbitrary beep sound:
[Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android)

All I want is to play it only in one ear and shift between playback in either ears. Anybody has an idea of how this can be done?

Comment: so you would have to use CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO for the format and encode three arrays one for the left ear, one for the right, and both ears

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458780/sending-a-buzz-sound-to-ear-bud-left-or-right duplicate

Comment: What exactly do you mean by encoding for different ears? I have tried switching the level of volume between ears, but it does not work. Can you please explain how to encode for different ears?

Comment: send me your current code via email and ill test and see what I can do .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make three different stereo soundclips where you have sound in left, right and both channels and then play them with SoundPool

Comment: So far I have not had success with generating tones. I guess I will have to use your method. Can you please tell me if you know how to generate these soundclips on pc?

Comment: I used audacity as well in the end. Its a pretty handy tool to create sound, using android I have not had any success in generating the beeps on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs you can control the output with AudioFormat. Not sure if this gives you the precision you need though.

```
final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
```

Change to this for left channel output:

```
final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_FRONT_LEFT,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
```

Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat.html

Comment: using CHANNEL_OUT_FRONT_LEFT and CHANNEL_OUT_FRONT_RIGHT I am not able to play tone in one ear. There is no apparent effect of this. All the tones sound same, and they are coming from both earphones. I only want one earphone to work in the situation where I have to guide a person in either direction.